# mongodb error using mgo: net.OpError (net.timeoutError)

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I keep getting errors when writing to mongo at unpredictable times and would like to find out the reason.
I am using the mgo driver for Go. The error is of type `net.OpError`. Some of its relevant fields:

```
net.OpError{
  Err: net.timeoutError,
  Op: "read",
  Net: "tcp",
}
```

Currently I handle this error by reconnecting:

```
err := myType.mgoCollection.Insert(msg)
if err != nil {
    myType.mgoSession = myType.mgoSession.Copy()
    myType.mgoCollection = myType.mgoSession.DB("my_db_name").C("my_collection_name")
}
```

and re-submit. Sometimes this is enough, sometimes several retries are needed. And sometimes even after 10 retries (each around 1 minute) the error is still there (currently I break up after 10 retries).

I could not find anything suspicious in the mongodb logs and do not know where to look further.

Most of my writes to mongo are rather small, but twice a second there are somewhat larger writes (maybe 1 or 10 kb when represented as JSON string).

I have two separate processes and this error occurs for both of them at the same time.

Comment: Is Mongo on the same machine as the Go application? Same local network? This sounds like a network issue so I'd rule that out first.

Comment: @Adrian yes, it is the same (virtual) machine.

Comment: Are these processes running many concurrent requests? Are you closing your sessions when you're done with them? It could be you're over taxing the connection pool.

Comment: @Adrian I am using mongodb to log events. There are only two concurrent sessions in one Go process. Both are created via session.Copy() from a single "origin" session. These session.Copy() calls happen concurrently during startup. Normally I use these two sessions throughout the lifetime of the process. Access to each single session is serialized. I realize now that my reconnection logic (shown in the post above) does not close the old session before overwriting it with a new (copy). Other than that there is not really a need to close my sessions.

Comment: If you can observe it happening live, can you try connecting to mongo from the shell client when the app is having issues? Could be probative. I'd make sure you're closing dead sessions in your reconnect logic but you're right, it's probably not your issue here.

Comment: Observing it live is challenging, since it may happen after as long as 24 hours of running time (of my processes). And whenever I notice it, everything is back to normal (no need to restart mongod). But maybe I can write some code to run the mongo client with some query.